# Limit of sequence $x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof, cauchy-sequences

> For $\alpha \in (0,1)$ let the sequence $\{x_n\}$ be such that $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 1 $ and $x_{n+1} = \alpha x_n +
> (1-\alpha)x_{n-1},\quad n\geq1$. Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$.

My try:

Since $\alpha \in (0,1)\implies (\alpha-1)\in (-1,0)$

$\begin{align}|x_{n+1}-x_n|=&|\alpha -1||x_n-x_{n-1}|\\ &\vdots\\ &|\alpha -1|^n|x_1-x_0|\end{align} \implies \{x_n\} \rightarrow 0 $

Is there any alternative proof ?

Comment: ${x_n}\to0$ not true.

Comment: Can you please suggest what is wrong in my proof?

Comment: Oh! I guess I have shown that the sequence is convergent but not the limit.

Comment: $|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|\alpha-1|^n$, but it doesn't follow that $lim_{n\to+\infty}{x_n}=0$.

Comment: Below is my solution, you can prove by induction that $x_n$ satisfies all the conditions of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look for $x_n$ in the form $\lambda^n$
$$
\\\lambda^2=\alpha\lambda+(1-\alpha)
\\\lambda^2-1-\alpha(\lambda-1)=0
\\(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1-\alpha)=0
$$
$=>\lambda=1,\;\alpha-1=>x_n=A+B(\alpha-1)^n\\
0=x_0=A+B\\
1=x_1=A+B(\alpha-1)
\\B(\alpha-2)=1=>B=\frac{1}{\alpha-2}=>x_n=\frac{1}{2-\alpha}\Big(1-(\alpha-1)^n\Big)=>\lim_{n\to+\infty}{x_n}=\frac{1}{2-\alpha}
$

Comment: Can you please explain how $x_n=A+B(\alpha-1)^n$?

Comment: $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=\alpha-1=>x_n=A\lambda_1^n+B\lambda_2^n$

Comment: If I may ask how did you figure it out to assume $x_n$ as $\lambda ^n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence